# Which version of web.config is in use?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been given a compiled asp.net mvc 4.5 project. The project has both a web.config and a web.stage.config.

**How can I tell which web*config the project has been wired to use?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web.config is always used, the web.stage.config was probably created to make some kind of transformation or to stage the configuration to some test or quality environment. You can check csporj file and see if there is some logic written. The web.config is always used.

Answer (score 1):

Is the web.stage.config a web.config transform? If it is, it should be listed as a child of web.config within the Solution Explorer.

In this case, the nodes found within web.stage.config will override matching nodes within web.config. For all other nodes, web.config values will be used.

More info on web.config transforms can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx